# Why doesn't explode() work?

Tags: php

I'm using the below code section and can not get the explode() function to work.

```
$a="E:\xampp\htdocs\magento162\media\catalog\product\c\o\colorch091001-black-2.jpg";
$b=explode("\",$a);
print_r($b);
```

Why is there no output from the above code. The IDE provides a tip that there is an error, but I don't know where.

Thank you.

Comment: you must escape \ by another \

Answer (score 8):

Most likely, you have to escape the backslash "\" into a double backslash "\\", both in `$a` and in `("\"...` which becomes `explode("\\", $a);`

Even StackOverflow's syntax highlighting tells you there is an error :) (see your `print_r` in red?) :)

```
$a="E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\magento162\\media\\catalog\\product\\c\\o\\colorch091001-black-2.jpg";
$b=explode("\\",$a);
```

**Edit:** i'll explain further: in double quoted strings like `"...."`, the backslash is used to escape some special characters like:

\n = newline,

\t = tab,

\" = a double quote, which by the way generates your syntax error as the string is not "finished" and the parser treats `,$a);` and the rest as a continuation of the string...,

So in some cases `\` is not a "real" character on its own, and therefore it needs to be typed twice to mean a "real" backslash.
(It implies, as another user [@xdazz] said, that you could use single quotes strings `'...'` to avoid escaping).

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `\`.

```
$b=explode("\\",$a);
```

And you'd better use single quote for `$a`, or if the string contain some special char like `\n` which will considered as a newline code.

```
$a='E:\xampp\htdocs\magento162\media\catalog\product\c\o\colorch091001-black-2.jpg';
```

Comment: +1 for the single quote suggestion.